# Retrieving from a custom table in wordpress database

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

Using phpmyadmin,I created a table named 'wp_volume' in my wordpress database having three columns and inserted 5 rows. I want to retrieve data in the last row and use the values in my wordpress website. please help!

I am using database browser as a plugin.

This is my connect.php file in dreamweaver which gives the result i need. But connecting this file to wordpress is the problem.

```
function get_vol(){
    $server_name = "localhost";
    $user_name = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db_name = "theeasterntimes";    

    $conn = mysql_connect($server_name, $user_name, $password);
        if(!$conn){
            echo mysql_error();
        }

    $sql = " SELECT vol_id , number , price FROM `volume` ORDER BY vol_id DESC , number DESC LIMIT 1 ";
    mysql_select_db($db_name);

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
        if(!result){
            echo mysql_error();
        }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $vol_id = $row['vol_id'];
            $number = $row['number'];
            $price = $row['price'];
        }

    mysql_close();   
}


<?php 
//solution that worked for me
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT vol_id , number , price FROM `wp_volume` ORDER BY vol_id DESC , number DESC LIMIT 1" );
    $counter=1;

    foreach($result as $row){
        $row = get_object_vars($row);
        $vol_id = $row['vol_id'];
        $number = $row['number'];
        $price = $row['price'];}
        echo "Vol. " . $vol_id . " No. " . $number;
        echo "Price: USH " . $price;
?>
```

This actually worked for me.
Great thanks to vrajesh for all your efforts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this :

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("select * from `wp_volume`", ARRAY_A);
$counter=1;
   foreach($result as $row){
echo $row['vol_id'];
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the code in dreamweaver using a connect.php file and it runs well. But connecting this file to wordpress is the problem.

Comment: No error but i want to use the values from $vol_id, $number, $price in my wordpress website. So i think i need to first include my connect.php to my wordpress

Comment: please add wp_load.php in your php file

Comment: This is the error i get when i try the first solution: "Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\wamp23\www\WordPress\wp-content\themes\mh-magazine-lite\header.php on line 40" where line 40 has this code "$row-> $vol_id;" first line after the for loop

Comment: print_r($row)...inside foreach loop :)

Comment: and echo $row-> vol_id;

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp23\www\WordPress\wp-content\themes\mh-magazine-lite\header.php on line 41
this is the new error. and line 41 is "$row-> $vol_id;"

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp23\www\WordPress\wp-content\themes\mh-magazine-lite\header.php on line 41           .......................this is getting tricky

Comment: print_r($row)...inside foreach loop :)

Comment: stdClass Object ( [vol_id] => 3 [number] => 1 [price] => 1800 ) Vol. vol_id No. number          Price: USH price
I terminated the print_r($row) and that was displayed along with the website

Comment: same result after removing $

Comment: Got a solution. Included it in the question

Comment: hey you can make my answer as solution by tick right beside my anwser..:)